# MySQL avoid double entry, when entering 2 same records at same time

Tags: php, mysql, web, e-commerce

I have this doubt about: 
When two users click on book button, at the same millisecond, the MySQL database does the double entry. How do I avoid adding double data to my database?

References: 
Backend: PHP
Front-End: HTML/CSS/JS

I have tried giving a random break before executing the entry statement.

For example: When the user presses: book now, I will hold up the next process for a number of seconds. and then let it proceed to insertion of data into MySQL.

But this seems to be bad practice.

May I know any better way to solve this issue?

EDIT:For example, I have a theatre booking system.The situation is: two or more the users books the same slot at the same time and it gets  booked. Whereas one of them should get a success and the rest should get an error.

Comment: If you're using primary keys in your database table, MySQL will **not** create double entry. It will only execute one of the two queries and the other will fail, even if they are sent to the database at the exact time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For example, i have a theatre booking system. What happens is, both the users books the same slot at the same time and it gets  booked. Whereas one of them should get a error.

Comment: If your database is designed correctly, this should not happen. For example, if you use a table for booking time slots, where the primary key is the day and time, then you cannot have two entries in that table for the same timeslot.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent duplicate entries on the data the user just entered (only to prevent the double click on the submit button insert scenario) you can use several solutions:

- Use a javascript button which only fires once;
- Use an `UNIQUE INDEX` on the content & user_id.

The UNIQUE INDEX scenario can look as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE user_comments (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
comments VARCHAR(4000),
user_id INT NOT NULL,
md5sum_comments CHAR(32)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unique_comments ON user_comments(md5sum_comments,user_id);
```

The `md5sum_comments` is a md5sum over the comments column since the real comments can be to large for an index.

When you now insert the same comment for a user twice, one of the inserts will fail with a `NON-UNIQUE` index error from MySQL. Since you do not want to bother your user with this non-unique index issue, you catch that in php and ignore it in further processing.

Comment: i guess there is misunderstanding in the question. I have added "EDIT" for more precise issue. If that helps. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use the unique index solution for that: instead of comment, read `booked_slot` with in there a unique value, inserted into a `booked` table. However when now 2 bookings occur at the same time, one will succeed and the other user should get the error. In short: The `UNIQUE INDEX` is your friend in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

No double Entries will be posted to the database, if you use PrimaryKeys and the Auto Increment function in this PK column.

Comment: Sorry, not true: An auto-increment primary key only gets you a nice primary key, and does nothing against duplicate data fields

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For example, i have a theatre booking system. What happens is, both the users books the same slot at the same time and it gets  booked. Whereas one of them should get a error.